# Tofu substitute in no bake chocolate cake

Tags: substitutions, tofu

I recently tried a no bake chocolate cake which used tofu to give it its consistency. It would have been great if it didn't have that slight tofu taste.

What could I uses as a substitute for the tofu to avoid the tofu taste but keep the consistency similar?

The recipe I used:

- 2 parts butter
- 3 parts dark chocolate
- 3 parts soft tofu
- 2 parts sugar

Melted together and mixed until smooth then set to cool.

Comment: Gelatin comes immediately to mind; that recipe looks like nothing so much as a firm, dense chocolate mousse. You'd also likely want some milk/cream in there. I couldn't guess at the ratios offhand, though, so leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Is it intentionally vegetarian? @Sneftel assumes it doesn't have to be.  You may want to edit the question if so

Comment: I wondered the same thing. :-) If so, one could use agar... but, yech, agar.

Comment: It is not intentionally vegetarian.

Comment: What kind of tofu did you use?  It can make a difference.

Comment: Use fresher tofu so it doesn't taste as beany.

Answer (score 3):

This almost sounds like someone converted a classic mousse recipe to use tofu instead of dairy. My suggestion is to simply use any dairy with a consistency similar to your soft tofu, in the same ratio as the tofu. You can use cream cheese, if you are accustomed to the combination with chocolate. If you aren't, you might be unpleasantly surprised - in that case, take a less salty cheese, for example tvorog or ricotta. Fermented products will also work instead of cheese - you can use skyr or drained yogurt, maybe even creme fraiche.

Comment: Diary will probably suit my taste better. Not a big fan of the sour notes from creme fraiche or yogurt so will probably go for some type of cheese.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try avocado? It is often used for no bake vegan chocolate cakes, although I personally never tried it.

Otherwise to hide the tofu taste you could add more flavour like vanilla extract, coffee, chestnut cream... I often put vanilla soy yoghourt in my cakes, it gives a great taste and texture (in baked cakes).